# Isn't "of" redundant in "out of doors"?

Tags: prepositions

Not only does "out of doors" sound "rather archaic" to me, it sounds superfluous when English already uses "outdoor(s)". Am I correct? Or does "of" somehow distinguish "out of doors" from "outdoor(s)"?

> #### abroad [13]

> It was only in the 15th century that
> *abroad* came to mean ‘in foreign parts’. Earlier,
> it had been used for ‘**out of doors [boldening mine]**’, a sense still
> current today, if with a rather archaic air; but
> originally it meant ‘widely’ or ‘about’ (as in
> ‘noise something abroad’). It was formed quite
> simply from *a* ‘on’ and the adjective *broad*,
> although it was probably modelled on the much
> earlier (Old English) phrase *on brede*, in which
> *brede* was a noun, meaning ‘breadth’.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 2.

Comment: Certainly not archaic, and could be making a comeback. [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=outdoors%2Cout+of+doors&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coutdoors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20doors%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Coutdoors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cout%20of%20doors%3B%2Cc0). But, alas and alack, idiomatic English isn't always neat and tidy. We can't always pick and choose those expressions we consider more logical. English is first and foremost usage-driven. Even in this day and age, some redundancies are just international treasures.

Comment: https://www.allmusic.com/album/out-of-doors-piano-music-of-b%C3%A9la-bart%C3%B3k-mw0001651874

Comment: Sometimes, a slighly archaic form is useful in distinguishing one thing from another. The album title for this collection of works by Bela Bartok would not have been the same if were “Outdoors”.

Comment: Merriam-Webster says "outdoors" can be used as an adjective (as an alternative to "outdoor"), although I think some people would object. But using "out of doors" as an adjective would be even worse. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outdoor

Answer (score -3):

It may look inessential to hang on  to keeping up  ' of ' in ' out of doors '  in  these days of prevalence of internet lingo which easily  folds up any phrase or clause  into acronyms as exemplified in folding up of  the phrase  'as soon as possible ' into ASAP and the like , raising the hackles of grammarians though.
As one feels more  free to use  'outdoors' than ' out of doors '  as an adverb as in the sentence
He would like to spend outdoors  and also as a noun as shown in the sentence
He would like to spend time in the great outdoors  ,
one may usually tend to obviate the usage of ' of '.
None of the contemporary writers seems to stick to this old usage and hardly anyone is found interested in holding up this traditional tail ,which can no longer be safe from being scissored in the causal and uncaring  hands of the present generation .

Comment: [ASAP is something like seventy years older than the internet as we know it](https://www.etymonline.com/word/a.s.a.p.#:~:text=also%20asap%2C%20adverbial%20phrase%20pronounced,phrase%20as%20soon%20as%20possible.)